# Pynput: detecting global hotkey blocks wxPython frame

Tags: python, wxpython, pynput

I am trying to toggle between `show()` and `hide()` on a wxPython frame by pressing a global hotkey. I have two obstacles with the following code.

Firstly, I am unable to pass "`self`" to the `keyboard.GlobalHotKeys` function. This is a scope issue as far as I can tell but how do I resolve it?

Secondly, the `with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys() as x` is blocking the rest of the code from running. Reading the [pynput documentation](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard) I got the impression it would be non-blocking.

The code provided here is an example. In my real program have a tray icon to indicated the program is running. I want several hotkeys but ran into this issue while implementing it. I understand the issue may have to do with threading. I have been trying to read up on wxPython's thread handling but it is way too advanced for me at the moment.

Thank you.

```
import wx
from pynput import keyboard

class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, title="title")

        def show_panel(self):
            if self.Show() == True:
                self.Show()
            else:
                self.Hide()

    def h_show(self):
        print('<ctrl>+s pressed')
        self.show_panel

    with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({'<ctrl>+s': h_show}) as x:
        x.join()

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex = Test(None)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I redid everything for the 4th time and realised what I did wrong. This does not answer my question but it does do what I want.

```
import wx
from pynput import keyboard

class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, title="title")


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex = Test(None)
    def show_panel():
        if ex.Show() == True:
            ex.Show()
        else:
            ex.Hide()

    listener = keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({'<ctrl>+s': show_panel})
    listener.start()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```